# CoredataCloudkit not work in production mode after submitting to app store

Tags: swift

I have used cloud kit for storing users data(Core data + Cloud kit ). In development mode it works perfectly. When it is in live data not store in iCloud. After deleting and re-install app, previous data not found. Please suggest proper way of submitting app which use core data + cloud kit in app store.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/DeployingYourCloudKitApp/DeployingYourCloudKitApp.html):

> After you finalize your schema and test your app in the development
> environment, you are ready to deploy the schema to production.
> Deployment promotes the schema to the production environment, **but it
> doesn’t copy the records in the development environment to the
> production environment**.

There are the steps:

To deploy a schema to production:

1. In CloudKit Dashboard, click "Deploy to Production…” button.
2. Review the changes that are going to be deployed.
3. Click “Deploy Changes.”

Verify Your Steps
Verify that the schema was copied to the production environment.

To view the production schema and data

1. Click Data in the Production Environment.
2. Click Record Types in the tab bar.
3. Select the record type you want to view.

this is how your [CloudKit Dashboard](http://icloud.developer.apple.com) should look like if you deployed the production schema:

[image]